# How to loop through the same array object n number of times

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I need to go through the same object and print it, according to the n number of meals, that the user has. I have the following arrays

```
[id, name, food1, food2, food3],
[id, name, food1, food2, ''],
[id, name, food1, '', '']
```

in the database it should be something like this:

```
1 | Ronald| chicken rice     | NoFood1
2 | Ronald| Tortillas azadas | NoFood2
3 | Ronald| stewed chicken   | NoFood3
4 | Paul  | Arepas           | NoFood1
5 | Paul  | Torillas         | NoFood2
6 | Raul  | noodles          | NoFood1
```

Because the records are based on the amount of food per user, but with the code I have I bring me the first food of each object, I was seeing that there are examples with linkedlist and .push, but good if you have to use another for I do, but if you could show me more or less how it would be please with the code I have or if there is another implementation and I am very grateful for your comments.

```
My function

ConditionDataToSend(lines, values: Array<any>){
while (lines !== null) {
const info: FoodDto = {food: '', name: '', id:0, noFood:''}

if (values.length >= 4 && values[4] !== '') {

    info.name = values[1]
    info.food = values[2]
    info.noFood = 'food1'
    info.id = id

    return info
}

if (values.length >= 5 && values[5] !== '') {
   
    info.name = values[1]
    info.food = values[2]
    info.nofood = 'food2'
    info.id = id

    return info
}

....
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly confused by the question (particularly the `noFood` property), but does this do what you want?

```
const data = [
  [1, 'Jim', 'raspberry', 'blackberry', 'lingonberry'],
  [2, 'Tina', 'boysenberry', 'strawberry', ''],
  [3, 'Sarah', 'blueberry', '', '']
];

function infoTransform(values) {
  return values.map(value => {
    [id, name, ...foods] = value;

    return {
      id,
      name,
      foods: foods.filter(food => food !== '')
    };
  });
}

console.log(infoTransform(data));

/* Log:
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Jim',
    foods: [ 'raspberry', 'blackberry', 'lingonberry' ]
  },
  { id: 2, name: 'Tina', foods: [ 'boysenberry', 'strawberry' ] },
  { id: 3, name: 'Sarah', foods: [ 'blueberry' ] }
]
*/
```

EDIT: Updated code with `noFood`:

```
const data = [
  [1, 'Jim', 'raspberry', 'blackberry', 'lingonberry'],
  [2, 'Tina', 'boysenberry', 'strawberry', ''],
  [3, 'Sarah', 'blueberry', '', '']
];

function infoTransform(values) {
  return values.map(value => {
    // Destructure
    let [id, name, ...foods] = value;

    // Filter out empty strings
    foods = foods.filter(food => food !== '');

    // Set food and noFood properties
    let noFood = null;
    let food = null;

    if (foods.length === 1) {
      noFood = foods[0];
      food = foods[0];
    } else if (foods.length > 1) {
      noFood = foods[foods.length - 1];
      food = foods[0];
    }

    return {
      id,
      name,
      food,
      noFood
    };
  });
}

console.log(infoTransform(data));

/* Log:
[
  { id: 1, name: 'Jim', food: 'raspberry', noFood: 'lingonberry' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Tina', food: 'boysenberry', noFood: 'strawberry' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Sarah', food: 'blueberry', noFood: 'blueberry' }
]
*/
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply, the property "noFood": is set statically depending, if in the position, if it is value [4], then "noFood" = 'food1', there is an element in position 5, that is, values ​​[5 ], then "noFood" = 'food2'

Comment: So `noFood` is always just the last element of the array? I don't understand why it's called `noFood`.

Comment: because the logic of the project wants it that way, and if always, it will be the last element

Comment: Okay, I made an edit. Is that the behavior you want?

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your answers, really, but ok, where did you put noFood: 'lingonberry', it would be 'food1', in noFood: 'strawberry', it would be 'food2' and in noFood: 'blueberry', instead of blueberry, it would be 'food3'

Comment: Okay, but I'm assuming the data isn't always going to be `'food1'`, `'food2'`, `'food3'`. Sometimes it's going to be chicken rice, tortillas azadas, etc. 

Or am I wrong? Can you post an exact output you want for a particular input? Maybe that would be easier.